# What are the capabilities of .NET in AutoCad

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, objectarx

Can anyone describe what you can create in C # in Autocad? 
I would like to improve the work in the design office, but I do not know what my options are.

- Can I create new objects?
- Overlays forming an aomomatically drawing based on the given data
- other

On the net I found only two blogs with posts from a few years earlier. There is nothing new.

Can anyone recommend any interesting articles, guides?

Any help will be helpful to get started. I know there is documentation but I will need some explanation step by step how everything works.

Comment: check out the [Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info)

Answer (score 3):

What you mentioned is possible. The API basics are the same since version 2007 (with incremental updated since and a couple binary breaks, but the code remains similar). For a new development, use the oldest version you plan to support (the last binary break release was 2013)

Visit the [AutoCAD DevCenter](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=1911627&siteID=123112) and check:

- [Wizard for Visual Studio](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/ObjectARXWizards-2018.zip)
- [Developer Guide](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-C3F3C736-40CF-44A0-9210-55F6A939B6F2)
- [Training material](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad2018_dot_net_training.zip)
- [Webinars (Sessions 1-8)](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/devtv/)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create new objects with the AutoCAD .Net API, below is an example [I wrote a while ago](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/how-to-create-mleader-objects-in-net.html), that creates a MLeader.

The .Net API is a managed wrapper around the C++ ObjectARX API, so it covers most of what the C++ API is capable of. The one thing that it cannot do is to derive custom classes from native ones, for Example `AcDbLine` cannot be extended through .Net. To achieve that you need to use the C++ API and can write a custom .Net wrapper in C++/CLI to expose it to .Net, then you will be able to instantiate your custom classes from .Net similarly to the built-in ones.

Modifying the behaviour of built-in entities can however be achieved directly in .Net by using [overrules](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/overrules/).

If your plugin is supposed to work only on Windows, then .Net is a more convenient choice than C++ and more flexible to implement UI's.

[CommandMethod("netTextMLeader")]
    public static void netTextMLeader() {

```
  Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

  Database db = doc.Database;

  Editor ed = doc.Editor;

  using (Transaction Tx = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) {

    BlockTable table = Tx.GetObject(
     db.BlockTableId,
     OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;


    BlockTableRecord model = Tx.GetObject(
      table[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
      OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;


    MLeader leader = new MLeader();

    leader.SetDatabaseDefaults();

    leader.ContentType = ContentType.MTextContent;


    MText mText = new MText();

    mText.SetDatabaseDefaults();

    mText.Width = 100;

    mText.Height = 50;

    mText.SetContentsRtf("MLeader");

    mText.Location = new Point3d(4, 2, 0);

    leader.MText = mText;

    int idx = leader.AddLeaderLine(new Point3d(1, 1, 0));

    leader.AddFirstVertex(idx, new Point3d(0, 0, 0));

    model.AppendEntity(leader);

    Tx.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(leader, true);

    Tx.Commit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

With .Net can you create a new Object?
The answer is No. You need to use ObjectArx for that. However, with .Net you can modify how an object looks like. For example you can modify a line to look like an arrow. Not only how it looks but also how it behaves. So there is enough flexibility in .Net that is enough to compensate for the need to create new objects. Basically with .Net you have the power of windows and autocad.

A good resource of .Net samples is through the interface [by Kean Walmsley](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/). Try to go through this blog and you will learn more about .Net capabilities in AutoCAD than what I would ever be able to describe.

Comment: "With .Net can you create a new Object? The answer is No." - Wrong. 
[Create a Line Object (.NET)](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-47E8A12E-2ED4-4E78-ADA3-AAC9B4223C3C-htm.html)